Jittered output from depth_image_proc register node
We have a depthai camera shooting color images at 5Hz and depth images at 10Hz. The camera node is connected to a depth_image_proc register node that registers the color and depth images. The register node is connected to a third node that does something with the registered depth images. We added diagnostics to the camera node and the third node for logging message frequency and delay.
This pipeline works well for about 40~70 mins. After that it starts dropping messages. I added a plot below showing the delays from the camera node's outgoing messages, the third node's incoming registered depth images (orange line), and the third node's outgoing messages (purple line). I couldn't add the message delays from the register node itself because it doesn't support diagnostics, so adding the third node's incoming message delays was the next best option.

A bit after 4300 seconds, the plot starts showing numerous gaps between the third node's incoming registered depth messages, as well as big spikes in message delays. The camera node keeps pretty stable. I also don't think that the third node causes trouble as it doesn't take much computation. So it looks like something goes wrong in the register node? But we're unsure would it could be. Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.
